# Add music to dialogflow

Tags: node.js, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am trying to add music into my dialogflow agent. I don't want to add it from the dialogflow console and I wish to add it from the webhook. Can you please tell me how to add the music from the webhook. I am trying this code but it's not working:

```
app.intent('Music', (conv) => {
    var speech = '<speak><audio src="soundbank://soundlibrary/ui/gameshow/amzn_ui_sfx_gameshow_countdown_loop_32s_full_01"/>Did not get the audio file<speak>';
});
```

Also I want to use one interrupt keyword which will stop this music, is there any predefined way or if user defined, how to interrupt the music and proceed with my other code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, to be able to add music, it needs to be hosted on a publicly accesible https endpoint, see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/df-asdk/ssml#audio). So make sure you can access your file even when using a private browsing mode such as incognito on chrome.

Secondly, If you choose to use SSML to play your audio, the audio will become part of the speech response. By doing this, you won't be able to create any custom interruptions or control over the music. The user can only stop the music by stopping your action or saying "Okay Google" again to interrupt your response.

If you would want to allow your users to control the music you send to them, try having a look at the [media responses](https://developers.google.com/assistant/conversational/prompts-media#behavior) within the actions on google library.

Comment: you mean "Okay Google" can interrupt my music and the code next can be executed?

Comment: The user can say "Okay Google" to interrupt the on going response (in your case, the music) and tell it to do something else. For instance, trigger a different intent or exit your action

Comment: After the music I have one code that asks the question but if I am saying "Okay Google" to interrupt the music, it goes to next intent and does not record the response of the current intent

Comment: If you say Okay Google you interrupt the whole response from the bot, that is normal. As I mentioned before, if you add SSML audio, it becomes part of the response, so you will have to wait for the music to end or implement some more advanced SSML techniques, here is a blog on how to do that: https://medium.com/google-developers/advanced-ssml-for-actions-on-google-5cea45d868c9

Comment: Okay. Thank you @Jordi